# ContentPropertyAttribute missing in Button content error

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am new in the .net dev world and i have probbably a handable error here but i don't know how to do it. The error is: Position 15:16: "Cannot set the content of button as it doesn't have a ContentPropertyAttribute". So here is my code:

`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="PlantsApp.HomePage"
         Title="Home">

<ContentPage.Content>

<ScrollView>

  <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="White">
    <Image x:Name="plantsOk" Source="Resources/PlantsOk.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
    <Label x:Name="plantsOkText" Text="Plants are doing well!" TextColor="#005329" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Padding="10">
      <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <Button x:Name="myPlants"  WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="MyPlants.png"></Image>
            <Label >My plants</Label>
          </StackLayout>
        </Button>

        <Button WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" >
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="ToDo.png"></Image>
            <Label >To Dos</Label>
          </StackLayout>

        </Button>
        <!--
          <Label>To Do</Label>-->
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
        <Button x:Name="history" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="History.png"  ></Image>
            <Label >History</Label>
          </StackLayout>

        </Button>
        <!--
          <Label>History</Label>-->

        <Button WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" >
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="PlantsBook.png"></Image>
            <Label >Plants Book</Label>
          </StackLayout>

        </Button>
        <!--<Image Source="Resources/PlantsBook.png"></Image>
          <Label>Plants book</Label>-->
      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>`
```

Comment: You need to improve this question. Links to code are not sufficient. Links to images of code are not acceptable. Please add the actual program text.

Comment: here is the code @AluanHaddad

Answer (score 0):

A `Button` is not a container, so it cannot contain a `StackLayout`.  A `Button` has explicit properties for setting it's `Text` and `Image` values

```
<Button WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Image="ToDo.png" Text="To Dos" />
```

Comment: i tried to use StackPanel, but it tells me that this type cannot be found  in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

Comment: if i use your example the text and pic will be alligned horizontally, and i want the text under the picture.

Comment: the default button doesn't support that.  Your best bet would be to use a StackLayout with a Label and an Image and add a GestureRecognizer to it to simulate the behavior of a button